# Should a surrogate PK plus a unique column be used or a natural PK using the unique column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Given: tX_1.name can never be NULL, has variable length up to 45 characters, and must always be unique.

What factors influence whether a surrogate PK plus a unique column should be used (Schema 1) or whether a PK natural key using the first table's unique column as its PK (Schema 2)?

[image]
Schema 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1_1 (
  idt1_1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idt1_1),
  UNIQUE INDEX name_UNIQUE (name ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1_2 (
  idt1_2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  t1_1_idt1_1 INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idt1_2),
  INDEX fk_t1_2_t1_1_idx (t1_1_idt1_1 ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t1_2_t1_1
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_1_idt1_1)
    REFERENCES t1_1 (idt1_1)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1_3 (
  idt1_3 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idt1_3))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1_1_has_t1_3 (
  t1_1_idt1_1 INT NOT NULL,
  t1_3_idt1_3 INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (t1_1_idt1_1, t1_3_idt1_3),
  INDEX fk_t1_1_has_t1_3_t1_31_idx (t1_3_idt1_3 ASC),
  INDEX fk_t1_1_has_t1_3_t1_11_idx (t1_1_idt1_1 ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t1_1_has_t1_3_t1_11
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_1_idt1_1)
    REFERENCES t1_1 (idt1_1)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_t1_1_has_t1_3_t1_31
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_3_idt1_3)
    REFERENCES t1_3 (idt1_3)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Schema 2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2_1 (
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2_2 (
  idt2_2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  t2_1_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idt2_2),
  INDEX fk_t2_2_t2_11_idx (t2_1_name ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t2_2_t2_11
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_1_name)
    REFERENCES t2_1 (name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2_3 (
  idt2_3 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idt2_3))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2_1_has_t2_3 (
  t2_1_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  t2_3_idt2_3 INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (t2_1_name, t2_3_idt2_3),
  INDEX fk_t2_1_has_t2_3_t2_31_idx (t2_3_idt2_3 ASC),
  INDEX fk_t2_1_has_t2_3_t2_11_idx (t2_1_name ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t2_1_has_t2_3_t2_11
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_1_name)
    REFERENCES t2_1 (name)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_t2_1_has_t2_3_t2_31
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_3_idt2_3)
    REFERENCES t2_3 (idt2_3)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: maybe interesting? [What should I choose for my primary key?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150511162734/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html). Which I found in: [Primary Keys: IDs versus GUIDs](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/)

Comment: @RyanVincent  Yes, interesting, but similar to what I have previously read.  My question is specifically why not to use a unique key as a natural PK.

Comment: imo, 1) It depends on your particular entity. My issue is that for complex entities people, etc. then the 'natural' key is a multi column value to make it unique. Or, if only one identifier is used then there are two issues with it. a) it is readable so is characters, i.e longer than an integer. b) it can change over the lifetime of the entity. ;-/ So, imo, use an integer id column that the database engine can use to look after the relationships. And the 'natural' keys as unique index columns that I can use to query the data.

Comment: Just ask yourself the question: what will happen if t2_1.name would change? (Will it ever change? is another question) See also: data-vault.

Answer (score 0):

Your many-to-many relation between t1 and t3 is inefficient in a few ways.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

I often use a `UNIQUE` key for the PK.  I reviewed a large number of tables that I have designed; only 1/3 have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the PK.  Some considerations (*assuming* InnoDB):

- Each secondary key includes all the columns of the PK; this *may* lead to bulkiness.
- Because of 'clustering' of the PK, it is faster to look up a row by the PK than by a secondary key.
- `FOREIGN KEYs` have a cost -- a lookup is done to check the implied 'constraint'.  Often code is written in such a way that a FK violation cannot occur, thereby making the FK unnecessary overhead.  (Others say FKs are 'good'.)
- A table with a thousand rows is so small that these questions are not very important.  A million rows will make them important.  A billion rows, and we need to discuss a lot more things.

Back to your question...

`INT` is 4 bytes; `VARCHAR` is variable and you have not provided an average length.  Hence, it is hard to compare.  Your schema *will* get more complex.  You *will* add more columns and more indexes, so the relevance of my comment about secondary indexes is yet to be determined.  You may decide that 45 is not enough.  Etc, etc.

Bottom line:  Flip a coin to decide which Schema to start with, then learn from the Schema as it matures.